# How to remove extra object properties that don't comply with the typestript interface?

Tags: typescript

I have this code, There's no error showing but clearly there's an error:

```
import axios from 'axios'
interface Character {
    name: string,
    birthday: string 
}

const url = 'https://breakingbadapi.com/api/characters'
async function char(): Promise<Character[]> { 
    return await axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
}

(async function() {
    
let chacater: Character[] = await char(); 
console.log(character[0]) 
})()
```

There are a lot of properties in each character object. I just want the name and brithday, so I specified them in the `Character` interface

But when I console log `character[0]` I get more than just name and birthday.

Should everything else have been filtered out, or should I so some sort of error?

Comment: TypeScript does **not** change the runtime behaviour of your code. It will never filter or modify anything during runtime. It is just there to provide compile time definitions to avoid errors when writing the code. You will have to remove these properties yourself if you don't want them.

Comment: Like @TobiasS.'s comment. Typescript does not automatically remove extra properties that are not present in the interface you have defined. You have to remove it manually. I found 1 question similar to yours and the answer has a clear way to remove the extra properties. You can find more here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087922/typescript-filter-object-by-interface-or-class

Answer (score 1):

When you define an interface in TS, you basically tell TS that the object will contain only those keys and their corresponding types. It is upto you as the developer when defining a function that returns that type, to make sure it does.

You can write *char* function like below to filter out all other keys and make sure each *character* in the array has those keys:

```
async function char(): Promise<Character[]> {
  return await axios.get(url).then((res) =>
    res.data.map(({ name, birthday }) => ({
      name: typeof name === "string" ? name : "",
      birthday: typeof birthday === "string" ? birthday : ""
    }))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tobias S has correctly pointed out that my original answer didn't actually do what I thought it did - and after wrapping my head around the code for 15 minutes I have come to agree with his conclusion that this isn't actually possible with out of the box TypeScript.

I think it might be possible using https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys - a custom transformer that allows you to get the keys of a type at runtime.

So the code would look like this:

```
export function filterProperties(obj:any, allowedKeys:string[]) {
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (!allowedKeys.includes(prop as InnerComponentPropsKeys)) {
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

And you would need to pass it the allowed keys, retrieved using the `keys<T>()` method from the custom transformer. So something like this React example, where a parent component props extends the props of the child component, and I want to spread the props rather than repeat them all. For example:

```
interface OuterComponentProps extends InnerComponentProps {
  somePropThatIsUsedInTheOuterComponent: string;
}

const OuterComponent = (props: OuterComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
  const innerComponentProps = filterProperties(props, keys<InnerComponentProps>()) as InnerComponentProps;
  return <div>
    <div>
      {props.somePropThatIsUsedInTheOuterComponent}
    </ div>
    <InnerComponent {...innerComponentProps } />
  </ div>;
};
```

Ideally, you would wrap the whole thing in a generic helper method, like this:

```
export function filterProperties<T>(originalObject: T): T {
  const filteredObject = {} as T;
  const allowedProperties = keys<T>();
  allowedProperties.forEach((propertyKey) => {
    filteredObject[propertyKey] = originalObject[propertyKey];
  });
  return filteredObject;
}
```

But this doesn't work because unfortunately this custom transformer doesn't work with generic/dynamic types, so it's not easy to wrap this in a generic helper method as I had originally thought. (See https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys#note)

The other big downside is that it involves using a custom transformer, which isn't trivial either (see https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys#how-to-use-the-custom-transformer)

Comment: And how does the function ensure that only the keys of `T` are copied over?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it doesn't do what I thought it did. I thought the magic was in the "as Array<keyof T>" but prompted by your query I've stepped through the code to check my assumptions and they seem to be wrong. I think I need to withdraw this answer.

Comment: After spending way too long trying to get my original code working as I intended, I have to accept that your original conclusion is the right one, and this can't done, at least not with Typescript alone. I found a custom transformer that adds a keys<Props>() function, but it doesn't work with generics and dynamic types, so it's not a very neat solution. I've updated my answer in any case as it's better than my original take.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#skipping-all-properties-of-the-class). However, you need to use a Class definition instead of interface. BTW, you can also take advantage of [class-validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) which can guarantee the data you get is correct and intended.