# Is there a way to efficiently get only certain fields of an object based on a type definition in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given two types:

```
type AllValues = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string;
  e: string;
  f: string;
  g: string;
};

type SomeValues = {
  b: string;
  d: String;
  f: string;
  g: string;
};
```

And an object with all values

```
const AllValues: AllValues = {
  a: "Some value",
  b: "Some value",
  c: "Some value",
  d: "Some value",
  e: "Some value",
  f: "Some value",
  g: "Some value",
}
```

Is there a way to easily extract all the values from this object, into a new object that is only containing the fields that are defined in the second type? Without manually typing

```
const leanObject: SomeValues = {
  b: allValues.b,
  d: allValues.d,
  f: allValues.f,
  g: allValues.g,
};
```

Comment: TypeScript can't really change runtime vales so most likely not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Filter Object by Interface or Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087922/typescript-filter-object-by-interface-or-class)

Comment: also: [Filtering object keys with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882670/filtering-object-keys-with-typescript)